choose constraint from IIS to build penalty function
Suppose I have a single objective optimization model whose constraints are all composed of linear equations and linear inequalities, and now that it is proven to be infeasible in a calculation using the input data.
I calculate an IIS by https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041448572-How-does-Gurobi-compute-the-IIS-for-infeasible-models  's method, and then, if I understand correctly, I get a set of conflicting constraints, and removing any one of them makes the original model solvable.
My question is: If I want to put a constraint in IIS as a penalty function term into the objective function of the original model and remove it from the constraint so that the relaxed model can be solved, what criteria should I use to select constraints from IIS? Are there any proven methods that are easier to implement.

What you describe is a common misconception about IIS. Instead, removing any constraint from the IIS makes the resulting subsystem feasible but does not necessarily make the original problem feasible. In practice, you might need to find an IIS, remove a constraint, find another IIS, remove an additional constraint, and repeat several times until the resulting problem is feasible.

@RobPratt so what you're saying is, let's say I have a model that infeasible with five constraints, and now I calculate that the first three constraints make up an IIS. If I remove the first constraint, then the submodel of the remaining four constraints is solvable, but the original model of the original five constraints is still infeasible, is that true, or do I need to remove the first constraint and continue the computation, find the second IIS, and then remove one constraint from it until I can't find IIS? Is the submodel composed of the remaining constraints solvable?

No, in your example where the first three constraints form an IIS, removing the first constraint leaves the subsystem consisting of the second and third constraints feasible, but the last four constraints might still be infeasible.

Looks to me it is better to formulate an elastic version of the model, so that it is always feasible. Basically by adding expensive capacity. I do this for almost all production models, so the user never sees "infeasible, no solution".

@ErwinKalvelagen So assuming a constraint is infeasible because of insufficient stock of an ingredient, you just add a virtual ingredient to the model that can replace that ingredient but is more expensive? Can you show a simple example?

@RobPratt so I should compute IIS and remove one constr until the transformed model is infeasible,right?

No, you should remove one constraint at a time until the resulting problem is feasible.

I think that, when selecting constraints to relax (with penalties), you should look at the IIS from the perspective of the final decision maker. Which constraints do they think absolutely must be satisfied? For which constraints would violations be acceptable as a last resort but highly problematic? Which constraints are "soft" to start with (more preference than absolute requirement)?
In other words, choosing the constraint(s) to relax is partly mathematical (membership in an IIS) but more contextual.

Thx for help. The other question that bothers me is this, what form of penalty function is appropriate? I want to start with g(constr) = λ*max(constr, 0) to try the effect, where constr≤0, is this format appropriate

Solvers may not allow use of the max function in the objective. If the original constraint is $g(x) \le 0$ and you are minimizing, you can incorporate a surplus variable $s$ to make the constraint $g(x) - s \le 0$ and then add $\lambda s$ to the objective function, which is equivalent to using the max function but will be acceptable to any solver.

what if its an equality constraint? should I use an absolute value notation for this like |h(x) - a| for constr h(x) == a, or is it the same as an inequality, or does the equation have some of the same linearization tricks as the inequality?

Your solver might not be happy to see an absolute value function in the objective. The simple solution is to change $g(x)=0$ to $g(x)+s_1-s_2=0$ with $s_1$ and $s_2$ nonnegative variables and then penalize the sum $s_1+s_2.$

Thx，your suggestions help me a lot
